# Extract pitch information from audio file

Tags: command-line, software-rec, audio, csv

Is there a command-line utility which would allow me to extract pitch information from an audio file and store it in a numerical form (i.e. as a list of comma-separated values)?

Comment: Are you talking about something like the data which feeds [Audacity's Pitch (EAC) display](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/Track_Drop-Down_Menu) .. Aside from somehow tapping in to Audacity's source, I don't know of such a utiliy, but I'll be watching this space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a look at [pitchtrack](http://web.tiscalinet.it/mupuxeddu/software/pitchtrack/manual.html) but it only supports two output formats, its own (.pt) and PostScript if you use the included "pt2ps" tool.